# C lang Syntax Error missing ";" before "*"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, syntax-error

The error appears in the `List* next` line.

```
typedef struct {
    List* next;
    int data;
    int index;
} List;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no type `List` that is known to the compiler. You cannot use a type before it is defined. You need to use the struct tag if you want to use that type during the declaration: `typedef struct List { struct List *next; ...}` You might revisit your learning material that introduces linked lists. It should explain that topic.

Comment: This is surely a FAQ. Do we have any post that could be used as canonical dupe?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, the type `List` is not known when you use it. There are two solutions to this.

The first is to simply use `struct List *next`:

```c
typedef struct List {
   int n;
   struct List *next;
} List;
```

The other is to typedef `List` into existence *before* defining `struct List`.

```
typedef struct List List;

struct List {
   int n;
   List *next;
};
```

Which is better is opinion, and thus inappropriate for SO.